# wx.Choice not displaying right on Windows 10

Tags: windows, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm working on a project using Python 3.6.4 and wxpython 4.0.1 msw (phoenix). I'm developing on Mac, but one of the systems I'm deploying to is Windows 10. My code (stripped of everything irrelevant) looks like this:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Dropdown Test", size=(400,400))
        control_sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=3, hgap=10)
        label1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label="First Dropdown:", size=(120,35))
        control_sizer.Add(label1, (0,0), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label="Second Dropdown:", size=(120,35))
        control_sizer.Add(label2, (1,0), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        self.choice1 = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=["thing 1","thing 2","thing 3","thing 4"])
        self.choice2 = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=["stuff 1","stuff 2","stuff 3","stuff 4"])
        control_sizer.Add(self.choice1, (0,1), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        control_sizer.Add(self.choice2, (1,1), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(control_sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

On the Mac, everything looks exactly as I'd expect. On Windows, the dropdowns (wx.Choice controls) function properly -- I can select items -- but they don't show the currently selected item when they fold back up. Here's what they look like in comparison:

[image: Comparative screenshots of code running on Mac v Windows]

I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon much further experimentation, it appears that using explicit sizing on `wx.Choice` instead of relying on defaults fixes the problem of not seeing the current selection, but it still doesn't show any text in the `wx.Choice` box until the user has selected something.

That second problem is fixed by explicitly assigning a starting value instead of counting on the defaults. Neither of these is necessary on Mac, but appears to be required for Windows. This is the working code for `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Dropdown Test", size=(400,400))
    control_sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=3, hgap=10)
    label1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label="First Dropdown:", size=(120,25))
    control_sizer.Add(label1, (0,0), (1,1), flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label="Second Dropdown:", size=(120,25))
    control_sizer.Add(label2, (1,0), (1,1), flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    self.choice1 = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=["thing 1","thing 2","thing 3","thing 4"], size=(120,25))
    self.choice1.SetSelection(0)
    control_sizer.Add(self.choice1, (0,1), (1,1), flag=wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    self.choice2 = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=["stuff 1","stuff 2","stuff 3","stuff 4"], size=(120,25))
    control_sizer.Add(self.choice2, (1,1), (1,1), flag=wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, border=10)
    self.choice2.SetSelection(1)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(control_sizer)
```

I also added some spacing around the controls for aesthetics.